# Role based Login in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-hook

How can I implement Role based Login in Liferay. I have already created a Login Hook which redirects users to their site at the time of login.

Ex:

User 1 will got to site 1.

User 2 will got to site 1.

User 3 will got to site 2.

User 4 will got to site 2.

and if a user is not assigned to any site, will be directed to default login site.

Now, What I want is if User 1(role = administrator) Logs in should be redirected to page 1(administrator page) of site 1.

and User 2(role = manager) Logs in should be redirected to page 2(manager page) of site 1.

Based on their roles. Can this be possible ?. If yes please help regarding this as how to implement it.

I'll add my code below.

```
@Component
(
    immediate = true,
    property =
    {
        "key=login.events.post"
    },
    service = LifecycleAction.class
)

public class MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction extends Action 
{
    private final static String PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT = "/web";
    private final static String PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT = "/group";
    
    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ActionException
    {
        final long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest);
         
        String path = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH);
             
        try
        {
            path = getCustomLandingPage(httpServletRequest);
        }
        catch (PortalException e)
        {
            throw new ActionException(e);
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNotNull(path))
        {
            final HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
            httpSession.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, new LastPath(StringPool.BLANK, path));
        }
    }
    
    private String getCustomLandingPage(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws PortalException
    {
        String path = null;
        
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(httpServletRequest);
        
        List<Organization> orgs = user.getOrganizations();
        
        if(orgs != null && !orgs.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Organization org : orgs)
            {
                Group orgSite = org.getGroup();
                int publicPageCount = orgSite.getPublicLayoutsPageCount();
                int privatePageCount = orgSite.getPrivateLayoutsPageCount();
                
                if(publicPageCount > 0)
                {
                    path = PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT+ orgSite.getFriendlyURL();
                    
                    break;
                }
                else if(privatePageCount > 0)
                {
                    path = PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT + orgSite.getFriendlyURL();
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNull(path))
        {
            List<Group> sites = user.getGroups();
            if(sites != null && !sites.isEmpty())
            {
                for(Group site : sites)
                {
                    int publicPageCount = site.getPublicLayoutsPageCount();
                    int privatePageCount = site.getPrivateLayoutsPageCount();
                    
                    if(publicPageCount > 0)
                    {
                        path = PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT + site.getFriendlyURL();
                        
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(privatePageCount > 0)
                    {
                        path = PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT + site.getFriendlyURL();
                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNull(path))
        {
            path = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest), PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH);
        }
        
        return path;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** after the answer

```
2022-08-24 09:23:22.822 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2][MainServlet:526] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.custom.login.hook.MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction.getCustomLandingPage(MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction.java:847)
    at my.custom.login.hook.MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction.run(MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction.java:826)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.InvokerAction.run(InvokerAction.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action.processLifecycleEvent(Action.java:34)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:98)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:60)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.loginUser(MainServlet.java:1054)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:263)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Faulty Line**

```
        String path = null;
        final long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest);
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(httpServletRequest);

        //getting role IDs
// THIS LINE        Role roleAdministrator = roleLocalService.fetchRole(companyId, "Administrator");
        Role roleManager = roleLocalService.fetchRole(companyId, "Manager");
        
        if(roleLocalService.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(), roleAdministrator.getRoleId()))
        {
            //has adminrole
        }
        
        if(roleLocalService.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(), roleManager.getRoleId()))
        {
            //has adminrole
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can check roles with the RoleLocalService.

```
@Component
(
    immediate = true,
    property =
    {
        "key=login.events.post"
    },
    service = LifecycleAction.class
)

public class MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction extends Action 
{
    private final static String PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT = "/web";
    private final static String PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT = "/group";

    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ActionException
    {
        final long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest);
         
        String path = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH);
             
        try
        {
            path = getCustomLandingPage(httpServletRequest);
        }
        catch (PortalException e)
        {
            throw new ActionException(e);
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNotNull(path))
        {
            final HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
            httpSession.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, new LastPath(StringPool.BLANK, path));
        }
    }
    
    private String getCustomLandingPage(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws PortalException
    {
        String path = null;
        final long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest);
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(httpServletRequest);

        //getting role IDs
        Role roleAdministrator = RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(companyId, "Administrator");
        Role roleManager = RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(companyId, "Manager");
        
        if(RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(), roleAdministrator.getRoleId())) {
            //has adminrole
        }
        
        if(RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(), roleManager.getRoleId())) {
            //has adminrole
        }

        List<Organization> orgs = user.getOrganizations();
        
        if(orgs != null && !orgs.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Organization org : orgs)
            {
                Group orgSite = org.getGroup();
                int publicPageCount = orgSite.getPublicLayoutsPageCount();
                int privatePageCount = orgSite.getPrivateLayoutsPageCount();
                
                if(publicPageCount > 0)
                {
                    path = PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT+ orgSite.getFriendlyURL();
                    
                    break;
                }
                else if(privatePageCount > 0)
                {
                    path = PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT + orgSite.getFriendlyURL();
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNull(path))
        {
            List<Group> sites = user.getGroups();
            if(sites != null && !sites.isEmpty())
            {
                for(Group site : sites)
                {
                    int publicPageCount = site.getPublicLayoutsPageCount();
                    int privatePageCount = site.getPrivateLayoutsPageCount();
                    
                    if(publicPageCount > 0)
                    {
                        path = PUBLIC_PAGE_CONTEXT + site.getFriendlyURL();
                        
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(privatePageCount > 0)
                    {
                        path = PRIVATE_PAGE_CONTEXT + site.getFriendlyURL();
                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(Validator.isNull(path))
        {
            path = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PortalUtil.getCompanyId(httpServletRequest), PropsKeys.DEFAULT_LANDING_PAGE_PATH);
        }
        
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! for the answer. But I am getting following exception and previous code is also not working. And one more thing [//getting role IDs] which you added seems to be hard coded for only two roles but i want it dynamic am i right or wrong please tell. I'll include the stack trace of the exception above in the question please have a look.

Comment: I cannot see what is in line 847 of MyCustomLoginHookLoginPostAction. Please post this line +- 3 lines. How do you want to do that dynamically? Where are the dynamic information stored?

Comment: I have added the lines. in question. can we do it on the basis of role stored in the table in DB (lportal).

Comment: have you added the lines    //inject roleLocalService
    @Reference
    RoleLocalService roleLocalService; ?

Comment: Yes, I have added those lines. Again for checking purposes I copied your whole answer and replace it with mine but encountered the same error again.

Comment: I updated my answer and removed the injection and switched to static util classes of RoleLocalService.

Comment: thanks !! let me try it. I'll update in 5 mins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247508/discussion-between-ratzownal-and-sniper-reloaded).